# How does one know which operator appears in an OPE?

Tags: field-theory, conformal-field-theory

Let us consider a primary operator $\mathcal{O}$ in a free CFT. How would one find the OPE of:
\begin{equation}
 :\mathcal{O}^2(x): :\mathcal{O}^2(y):
\end{equation}
(where :_: denotes normal-ordering) ?
I know I can readily compute the 4-point function using Wick, but I'd like to know what can we said about the OPE. My guess is that only $:\mathcal{O}^2:$ and $:\mathcal{O}^4:$ can appear, but I don't know how to justify it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's true that OPEs in a free CFT are more constrained than what follows immediately from the spectrum and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry. For example, $\phi^n$ cannot appear in $\phi^k \times \phi^k$ if $n > 2k$.

However, if $\mathcal{O}$ is truly an arbitrary primary or even an arbitrary scalar primary, the fusion rules will be a lot more complicated than what you've stated. Taking $\mathcal{O} = \phi^2$ will allow $\mathcal{O}$ to appear in $\mathcal{O}^2 \times \mathcal{O}^2$ (with normal ordering implicit) as can be seen by evaluating the 3pt function with Wick contractions. And then there are primaries with spin, etc.

If the OPE is not an exhaustively studied one like $\phi \times \phi$, there's probably no shortcut besides working out several Wick contractions and using induction to prove patterns that arise.

**Edit**

Maybe it helps to say this. If $\mathcal{O}_i$ is an operator with $n_i$ fields and potentially many derivatives, $\mathcal{O}_3$ can appear in $\mathcal{O}_1 \times \mathcal{O}_2$ if $n_1 + n_2 + n_3$ is even and the sum of any two $n_i$ is at least as great as the third. Additionally, if two operators are identical, the third must have even spin. Maybe this selection rule is enough for what you need. But if not, working out the primary operators allowed by it is tedious in general.